# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ on Heroku with pika due to ProbableAccessDeniedError

Tags: python, heroku, rabbitmq, pika

I just set up a RabbitMQ add-on in heroku. After developing my app to queue up and consume messages running on a local instance, I deployed it to Heroku and have not been able to connect successfully yet. The username/password & hostname/port/vhost are all from `heroku config`. If I change the username or password, the error changes to `ProbableAuthenticationError` which makes me believe the authentication is at least correct, but likely an issue with my vhost or some other missing configuration. I haven't seen any similar questions on SO or after an hour of Googling that didn't address my issue.

I have tried both the `RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL` and `RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_TX_URL` environment variables for both sending and consuming, and no combination seems to work. Below is the code I have for attempting to connect.

```
url = 'small-laurel-24.bigwig.lshift.net'
port = 10019
vhost = '/notmyrealvhost'

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(url, port, vhost, credentials=credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

Is there something I'm missing or any way to figure out what specifically is configured wrong? I'm at a loss here. Much thanks in advance!

I am running pika 0.9.14, python 2.7.3.

Comment: Probably not it, but keep in mind that most vhosts don't have a ```/``` in their name. Default is ```/``` while others usually are named without the special character, e.g. ```notmyrealvhost```.

Comment: @eandersson I think you're right. I ended up solving it another way, but I have a feeling that was the case.

Comment: I added my own answer, with a basic explanation in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by using the `URLParameters` class on pika to parse the URL from Heroku's environment variable.

This takes the string like 
`amqp://username:password@small-laurel-24.bigwig.lshift.net:10018/notmyrealvhost` and parses everything as needed. I was unnecessarily complicating things by doing it myself.

Answer (score 9):

The problem was most likely that you added the forward slash character in your virtual-host. Many users confuse this with the forward slash being the root directory, but it is actually just the default virtual-host name.

Unless you actually named the virtual-host using a forward slash, the name will always be identical to the name you see in the management console, e.g:

- my_virtualhost and not /my_virtualhost

This is why your solution worked as you did not add the extra forward slash when using **URLParameters**.

Your original code would have looked like this using URLParameters:

```
amqp://username:password@small-laurel-24.bigwig.lshift.net:10018/%2Fnotmyrealvhost
```

While the working version you mentioned in your answer above does not have the forward slash (`%2F`) character.

```
amqp://username:password@small-laurel-24.bigwig.lshift.net:10018/notmyrealvhost
```